# WSOD afte uninstalling the Memcache module and deleting it's folder

Tags: caching

I've uninstalled the Memcache API and integration module from my site and then deleted it's folder from `sites/all modules`.

Then, my site was down, and a WSOD appeared instead.

I went to Drush and typed `drush cc all`, and then this came up:

[image]

Afterwards I restored the deleted memcache folder at sites/all/modules, and again typed drush cc all... Then the site came to work, but now when I run Drush I still so something wired:

[image]

1. Why I have a WSOD when I remove the module's folder if the module itself doesn't even enabled?...
2. How can totally delete the module?

---

Update for user - Les Lim:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the steps to install Memcache module is to add a line in your settings.php file that specifies a module file as a cache backend.

To uninstall the Memcache module, you will also need to remove that line in settings.php.  Until then, Drupal will be attempting to load a cache backend from a file that is no longer there.

Comment: I've made everything all memcache-related code in settings php as comment while in 777, and saved the file and changed back to 555. I've also updated the question with an image from my settings.php file, so you might tell me if something there is not correct.

Comment: Yes, all of that should be commented out if you are no longer using Memcache.

Comment: Well, strange, the site is still in WSOD and there seems to be another problem besides the one we discussed that also causes WSOD. I've opened another thread, for the people to come about this, here in DA. You are more than invited to take a look, and I would be honored: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178460/wsod-and-drush-cc-all-fail-after-deleting-a-view-of-a-long-time-ago-deleted-modu

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer in that question as well.