# WSOD and Drush cc all fail after deleting a view of a long-time-ago deleted module

Tags: wsod, javascript

### Background

Drupal 7.40 site, all is up2date, the site itself worked, until the last hour, just fine.

### The problem

I once had a module named [Flexslider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) and have deleted it 5 months ago. One of it's views and/or content types stayed alive and I've deleted it in the last hour; Since then there is a WSOD in my site and each time I try to flush all caches with Drush I get the following error about the impossibility to access a Flexslider file.

Any ideas why would that happen?

[image]

---

Image update for user - Les Lim:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I happen to know from [WSOD afte uninstalling the Memcache module and deleting it's folder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178453/wsod-afte-uninstalling-the-memcache-module-and-deleting-its-folder/178455) that you just stopped using Memcache, then I know that your Drupal site has just reverted back to using the database cache.

You probably had entries in your database cache from before you switched to Memcache in the first place.  Those really old database cache entries are now back in use.

You're trying to clear caches, which is absolutely the correct thing to do. However, there's a nasty bug in CTools that prevents you from clearing the cache if a particular CTools cache entry is broken: https://www.drupal.org/node/1775612

In this case, though, the manual fix is pretty simple. You need to truncate the `cache` table in your database. That should allow the cache to rebuild itself normally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer so much! I'm not sure what "truncate" means - I saw 3 different definitions in the dictionary, lol... Anyway, It sounds to me like partially deleting something from the *cache* table in my database? I guess anything that has to do with Flexslider? If yes, I guess I would be able to do so via PHPmyadmin > search > type there "flexslider" > set it to search at cache table > delete ?

Comment: TRUNCATE in SQL means delete all the rows from a table. I think you should be able to use Drush for this, even if the site is unresponsive. Try the following command: drush sqlq "TRUNCATE TABLE cache;"

Comment: If you have PHPMyAdmin, I think it's called "Empty Table" in that interface. I'm not sure.

Comment: In Drush, I get the output: ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'zantech0_Benia.cache' doesn't exist
Query failed.

Comment: Well that's not good. Did you install the site with a table prefix? The table won't be called "cache" exactly, then.

Comment: You can list the names of all tables that have the string "cache" in its name, just to check. That command is this: drush sqlq "SHOW TABLES LIKE '%cache%'"

Comment: I believe there is a table prefix for all my tables and that this prefix is "4bn_". I've no idea why it's there, maybe it's because the first time I installed the site was with softaculous, maybe it's because someone of the server support once changed it \ or it was added by a machine in some occasion --- In anyway I've updated the question with a screenshot with the table that I think I should empty (after a backup of course).

Comment: You found the right table. Go ahead and empty that one.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very very much for all the didactic and detailed help!, It enlightened me with both knowledge and confidence to do such actions in the future (I'm but a humble Javascript student). So, Thank you again! ^__^